# Header Content Range undefined with Axios and Vue CLI

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-cli

I'm trying to get the header "Content-Range" from the Axios response. My dev environment is created thanks to VUE Cli version 4.

My project is a little front-end tool in Vue 3, calling directly from the client an external API to retrieve data.

I can see the "Content-Range" header in the network tab, the response headers received from the API call. But with Axios response.headers I only have acces to Cache Control, Content Length and Content Type.

After some researches, I found that the server must have a header Access-Control-Expose-Headers with "Content-Range". Not sure which server it is, mine or the one of the third party API I'm using.

So I tried to update my webpack config in vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {        
      devServer: {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Range',
          'X-Custom-Foo': 'bar',     
        }
      }
    },
  }
```

Thanks to the custom header "X-Custom-Foo", I tested that this configuration is activated, but I still not have access to Content-Range in the headers from Axios.

What am I missing? Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I did a quick search, and I think you need to configure your ```Access-Control-Expose-Headers``` as a response header on the server.  [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer.

I did that without success, I think, but I'm not sure. This is what I explained in the second part of my post.

Comment: If you are calling the 3rd party API server directly - then those CORS headers must be returned by their server. If you're proxying the request through your own server (probably because you can't convince them to change the CORS configuration) - then your API/proxy server must provide this CORS header.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @IVOGELOV.

I don't understand. I have the Content-Range header in their API response if I check the network tab of the Chrome dev tool.

I just need to have access in my js script. It's not possible without creating a proxy and sending the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?

Comment: If you are not familiar with CORS - you should first read about the concept and what browsers require as HTTP headers from the servers. Then you will check if the `Content-Range` header is marked for exposing in the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header value, as pointed out by @Tim. If the API server does not expose the header for cross-origin requests - and you can't convince the API owner to change this behavior, then you will need your own API endpoint (on the same domain as your application) which will call the 3rd party API.

Comment: Thank you @IVOGELOV. I'm reading the CORS documentation to understand better.